# Python: How to check the status of a process executed by sendline

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am using the following code to execute a remote script. The execution might take a few seconds to complete and I don't want to block the code while the script is being executed. How can I check to see if the script has been executed and finished successfully?

```
import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.login (ip, username, password):
s.sendline('./script &')
```

If `sendline` is not the best way to go, please suggest an alternative.

Comment: What will you do while the script is running until it returns?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I will ssh to other servers and do other time consuming jobs on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your script write its exit status to a file when it finishes, then wait for that file to appear (by periodically looking for it, most probably):

```
(./script ; echo $? > exit_status) &
```

This assumes your script signals failure by exiting with a non-zero status code.